# how do i iterate across a json array?

Tags: javascript, json

how do i retrive the description from the following array in javascript: 
here's the JS:

```
$(function () {
    var description = data.output.description;
    $("#myinput").suggest({
        "filter": "(all type:/automotive/model)",
        "lang": "en",
        "key": "***",
        "output": "(description)",
        'limit': 40,
    }).bind("fb-select", function (e, data) {
        $("#response2 pre").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
        prettyPrint();
        $("#response2").show();
    }).bind("fb-select", function (e, data) {
        $('#output').append(data.name + ", " + data.output['description']);
    });
});
```

response:

```
{
  "mid": "/m/03mnql",
  "id": "/en/ford_f-series",
  "name": "Ford F-Series",
  "notable": {
    "name": "Automobile Model",
    "id": "/automotive/model"
  },
  "lang": "en",
  "score": 88.680244,
  "output": {
    "description": {
      "wikipedia": [
        "The F-Series is a series of full-size pickup trucks from Ford Motor Company which has been sold continuously for over six decades. The most popular variant of the F-Series is the F-150. It was the best-selling vehicle in the United States for 24 years, currently the best-selling truck for 37 years, and the best selling vehicle in Canada, though this does not include combined sales of GM pickup trucks. In the tenth generation of the F-series, the F-250 and F-350 changed body style in 1998 and joined the Super Duty series.\nDuring the post-World War II era, smaller Canadian rural communities had access to either a Ford dealer or a Lincoln-Mercury-Meteor dealer, but not both; a Mercury-badged version was sold at Lincoln-Mercury-Meteor dealers there from 1946–68. Other than the grilles, trim, and badging, these trucks were identical to their Ford counterparts."
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using what programming language?

Comment: If you're working in JavaScript, that's an object literal, not JSON.

Comment: @chepner Maybe read the question: "in javascript". I must admit that the "javascript" tag is really missing, though.

Comment: in response to the points made above i am adding in my JS. thanks for all the responses very very quick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objectVariableName.output.description;
```

This will return an object with a single key "wikipedia" that has an array value with one element, which is probably the description you want.

```
objectVariableName.output.description.wikipedia[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an object literal :

```
var description = data.output.description;
```

If this is yet JSON :

```
var description = JSON.parse(yourstring).output.description;
```

But seriously it doesn't look like you made a big effort.

Comment: thank you for the anwser, your very right i suppose i didn't make a huge effort.